# How can a Computer Engineer give up material needs and become Spiritual?

Tags: logic, theology

What do the Vedas and Bhagavad Gita ask to do when someone wants to devote himself completely to God and can give away material success and happiness for it? If so, how can the person earn a living for 2 times food and other basic needs?

For more details, consider a hypothetical Indian boy:

The boy graduated with B.E. Computer this year and was a topper in all years of graduation. He's of age 22 and previously did not believe in god. He did Computer Engineering due to his attraction to computers. He enjoyed doing programming. He got a selected in a renowned company through campus interview and had good salary.

But he left the company in some months due to few reasons. In the past year, he was occupied by thoughts like why does everything exists, what is the purpose of everything, how did first living cell form, why do all species want to survive, how could complex architectures like Ajanta-Ellora, Pyramids and other be built if the ancient people were less advanced, and many such questions, and he took these questions seriously.

After trying to search a lot of places, he was influenced by Vedas. He started believing in things other than just physical, specifically spiritual. He then read Bhagavad Gita and became a complete believer in God and message of Gita.

He realized that all the things he knew about computers was mere information, and not knowledge. True knowledge lies in Vedas, bhagavad gita, bhagavad purana, etc. He started to live a much simpler life, started giving up things giving bodily pleasures. He did not like doing programming as he used to do before. He now wishes to read and understand the Upanishads, the 4 Vedas, etc. He now seeks happiness is learning more from these.

But he worries that how will he earn money to have food for 2 times a day and other little things. He does not want to do a IT job again and want to give up material way of living.

What should he do?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy, SE. This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Philosophy as an academic discipline. The way you posed it, I don't think it even qualifies for the Hinduism SE. You will have to heavily revise it in order for it to be accepted.

Comment: I agree. If we had a LifeAdvice.SE this would fit nicely, but at it is I'm not sure it belongs anywhere.

Comment: he should save up some money and travel to the far east for a trip of a lifetime.

Comment: Workplace.SE might actually have something to say about this, though you would probably want to phrase it differently.

Comment: First I would like to encourage the boy to make a clear diagnosis of his situation.
Apparently he is disappointed from his current way of life: Disappointment about computer engineering itself or disappointed about the present job and the work in the present company? 

If he really wants to become a college professor he must continue his university study, to obtain a master degree and even a PhD. That’s a long way and presupposes  a strong interest in academic research. Of course, he can earn the necessary living and study fees by a part-time job, e.g. working as freelancer computer engineer.

Comment: If the boy really wants to study the Vedas, the Upanishads and other religious Hindu texts, I would recommend to start with a one-semester course on this subject. E.g. I took some online courses at Oxford Hindu center http://courses.ochsonline.org/course/index.php 
In addition, he can contact one of the local Hindu communities, which exist in capital towns in UK, USA and in other Western countries. It is a good experience to learn both the academic view on Hinduism as well as its religious base.

Comment: In any case, I consider it important to make his own judgement. For me it was not enough that some Westerners and many Hindus rhapsodize about the deep insights hidden in the Upanishads. I wanted to assess their value by myself. Hereby I found helpful the support from the academic domain.

Comment: @nir The boy lives in India itself

Comment: @JoWehler The boy lives in India

Comment: @AlexanderSKing I've edit the question description, added precise question in the beginning

Comment: @user5155835 After you edited your question it got a more specific aim. Do you know http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions? Here you may get a lof of qualified answers to your question, mostly from fellow companions from Hindu culture, laymen and sannyasins. - So take my comments above as written from a Westerner's stance, who brings into discussion the academic study of Hinduism ;-)

Comment: I vote for "reopen": After the edit the question fits into the domain of philosophy of religion.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing please can the question be reopened

Comment: @user5155835 the question is more specific and easier to understand, but now it seems that it is more appropriate for the hinduism SE, where people have more knowledge of the Vedas and the Gita. For what it's worth, if this boy thinks that becoming a ME professor is easier than being an IT engineer and that as such he can spend his time studying scripture, he would make a poor ME professor indeed. The Bhagavad Gita speaks about placing duty above all else. Wouldn't his principle duty in life be to his students an to his university, not to life as a monk?

Comment: @AlexanderSKing I've edited the question, removed the professor part and added how can the person earn a living for 2 times food and other basic needs by giving up material things

Answer (score 2):

There are many philosophers (and perhaps even a few theologians) in the field of programming, so the two aren't intrinsically incompatible.

If, however, the "boy" is interested in wholly devoting himself to religion, and if his material needs are modest, perhaps he should consider joining a religious order, or pursuing religious education, or seeking a job with a religious community service organization.  There's no particular reason to pursue material success if he no longer finds it meaningful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please name a few religious community service organisations where a JOB can be seeked?

Comment: Also, since the boy lives in India, any in India?